# polygons of SF object misalligned, possibly bbox issue

Tags: r, polygon, r-sf

So I have two SF objects, one polygon and one multipolygon class, representing neighbourhoods and sub-neighbourhoods of a city. Both come from ArcGIS and cover the exact same area. However, when I plotthese two objects the sub-neighbourshoods are slightly misalligned in my leaflet plot,
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmMQ0.png).
The original projections are:

```
iver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 92 features and 19 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 55500 ymin: 428647.4 xmax: 101032.6 ymax: 447000
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs

ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 7 features and 7 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 438682.1 ymin: 6771629 xmax: 512270.9 ymax: 6800944
epsg (SRID):    3857
proj4string:    +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
```

After which I changed both to WGS84 with st_transform.

the leaflet code is:

```
   leaflet(width = "100%") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.Terrain") %>%
  setView(lng = 4.314960, lat = 51.916024, zoom = 10) %>%
  addPolygons(data = rtdm_gebieden, weight = 2, color = "black", fillOpacity = 0.8, fillColor = groen_kleuren) %>%
  addPolygons(data = rtdm_buurten, weight = 2, color = "red")
```

I suspect it's because the bbox of the sf objects are slightly different

SF object 1

```
Geometry set for 92 features 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 3.940974 ymin: 51.84307 xmax: 4.602129 ymax: 52.0055
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

sf object 2

```
Geometry set for 7 features 
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 3.940748 ymin: 51.84212 xmax: 4.601808 ymax: 52.00453
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

I tried setting the bbox of one to that of the other, but using st_bbox doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code is not reproducible so we can only guess...My guess is that you have a projection problem. Probably you specify the wrong projection when you import your spatial object (with `st_read` or `read_sf`). I don't know which projection are used in The Netherlands but in Belgium we have 4-5 different national projections ("Belgian Lambert") and you typically have such kind of drift when you mix these different projections. If the native projection is missing in your original spatial layer it might require some trial and errors before finding the right one...

Comment: Or, the code / method you've used in ArcGIS is incorrect, thus producing the wrong shapes. No way to tell at the moment.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I added the original projections, as I didn't specify them in my R call. I was under the assumption that no matter which projection, you could transform it to a different one?

Comment: For the first spatial layer the epsg code is missing and the proj4 string is probably not complete. An additional `+towgs84` part is missing that could typically explain this kind of "shift" problem. See [here](https://epsg.io/28992) for the full version of the proj4 string and [here](http://postgis.17.x6.nabble.com/Coordinate-transformation-problem-td3528606.html) for a discussion on that topic (particularly the reply of "Jan Hartman"). Maybe you could first try to read the layer and specify the epsg code to override the existing projection information `read_sf(your_layer, crs = 28992)` .

Comment: Thanks Gilles! what you said proved to be correct. As this is the first time I work with geodata, I couldn't tell some elements to the projection were missing. I fixed it by specifying the projection in arcGIS before exporting the data.

Comment: @Gilles - perhaps write-up as an answer. I'm sure this would be useful to a few people.

Comment: @SymbolixAU You are right. Easier to find for me in the future too

Comment: SO a minor update: This only worked with one of the many projections. The rest still failed to allign. I'm still trying to figure out why!

Comment: So what finally worked (I figured it out) was pasting the +towgs84 part on the original proj4string

`WGS84_string2<- paste(proj4string(rtdm_beheergebieden),"+towgs=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725", sep = " ")`

After this, I assigned this new string to the spatialPolygonsDataframe
`proj4string(df)<- CRS(wgs84_string2)`

then, transform it to an sf file

`df<- st_as_sf(df)`
 and transforming it 
`df<- st_transform(df, 4326)`

Though I still don't fully understand why this works

Answer (score 1):

The solution found after discussion in the comments

This kind of slight shift between different spatial datasets seems to be frequent particularly with Belgian (eg Belgian Lambert EPSG 31370) and Dutch spatial layers.

The first SF object show this at import :

```
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs
```

The EPSG code is missing and a quick search on the beginning of the proj4 string points to the Amersfoort projection EPSG:28992 with the following proj4 string :

```
+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs
```

The `+towgs84` part at the end that is laking in the original SF object is the source of the shift observed. Depending on the reference database it will be present or not...
According to Jan Hartman from [this Postgis forum answer](http://postgis.17.x6.nabble.com/Coordinate-transformation-problem-td3528606.html) :

> The problem is that the National Grid has a different Datum
>   than WGS84: it uses a slightly different ellipsoid to approximate the
>   surface of the earth. With the standard PROJ epsg-file, this Datum
>   difference will *not* be computed, and you get differences up to 100
>   meters. For a complete transformation to WGS84 you need an extra
>   "+towgs" parameter in the PROJ parameter string.

One solution applied by @Sjoerd Braaksma was to go back to the software that had generated the layer (ie ArcGIS) and fix the projection there.

An other solution is to force R to assign the projection via the epsg code when you import the data in R to ensure that the right projection will be used:

```
SF <- read_sf(your_layer, crs = 28992)
```

This will cause the following warning that can be ignored here because indeed we don't want to reproject this data:

```
Warning message:
st_crs<- : replacing crs does not reproject data; use st_transform for that  warning
```

Here is an example with a Belgian dataset :

```
> SF <- read_sf(dsn = "mylayer.shp")
> SF
## Simple feature collection with 2664 features and 19 fields
## geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
## dimension:      XY
## bbox:           xmin: 22265.45 ymin: 21162.99 xmax: 295157.4 ymax: 244027.9
## epsg (SRID):    NA
## proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=49.8333339 +lat_2=51.16666733333333 +lat_0=90 +lon_0=4.367486666666666 +x_0=150000.01256 +y_0=5400088.4378 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs
```

Force the projection :

```
> SF <- read_sf(dsn = "mylayer.shp", crs = 31370)
## Warning message:
## st_crs<- : replacing crs does not reproject data; use st_transform for that 

> SF
## Simple feature collection with 2664 features and 19 fields
## geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
## dimension:      XY
## bbox:           xmin: 22265.45 ymin: 21162.99 xmax: 295157.4 ymax: 244027.9
## epsg (SRID):    31370
## proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=51.16666723333333 +lat_2=49.8333339 +lat_0=90 +lon_0=4.367486666666666 +x_0=150000.013 +y_0=5400088.438 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-106.8686,52.2978,-103.7239,0.3366,-0.457,1.8422,-1.2747 +units=m +no_defs
```